# Sorting SQL Query From Second Query

Tags: php, sql

I'm looking for some help on how to sort my SQL query based on a separate row. Column 3 is a date and time here.

```
Table: 
col1   col2   col3   col4
X1     Y1     Z1      X1
X2     Y1     Z1      X2
X3     Y2     Z1      X1
X4     Y2     Z2      X2
X4     Y1     Z4      X4
```

What I have right now which obviously doesn't work is:

```
SELECT col1 FROM Table WHERE col2 = Y1 ORDER BY (Select col3 FROM table WHERE col4=col1 && col2 = Y2)
```

So for me, I want to grab all the NEW posts in a forum, and order them by when the last post in the thread occurred (date/time) then display them with the most recent replies to the oldest replies.

Below is actual table w/ expected results.

```
post_id post_type   post_time         thread_id
1           o       4/29/2013 15:04      1
4           r       4/29/2013 15:05      1
16          o       7/7/2013 20:29       16
17          o       7/7/2013 20:29       17
25          r       9/7/2013 0:10        1
33          r       9/7/2013 12:52       17
34          r       9/7/2013 12:52       1
35          o       9/7/2013 13:12       35
```

So here o/r represents if it's a new post (o) or a reply to a thread (r) and if it is a reply, the thread_id relates the reply to the post_id of the original post. What I need to do is order the threads by last post time (most recent to latest). So expected results would be...

```
35
1
16
17
```

Comment: Please, add actual data. It is impossible to understand this question this way. Create a table with decent column names and add sample data. Then create a similar table for the OUTPUT of your query. Then it is almost not necessary to explain anything

Comment: Updated my question, hopefully it's enough to go off of.

Answer (score 0):

take out the subquery in your ORDER BY clause and it should work

```
SELECT col1 
FROM Table 
WHERE col2 = Y1 
ORDER BY col3
```

Comment: But on the first select I'm grabbing all the col1 values where col2 = Y1 and then I want to sort those results where col2 = Y2 and col3 = col1 so unfortunately this won't work.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question.  From what I see, it sounds like you need the most recent post from each thread, ordered by the post_time.  something like this, maybe?
`SELECT max(post_id) as latest_post_id
    , max(post_time) as latest_post_time
    , thread_id
FROM Posts
GROUP BY thread_id
ORDER BY latest_post_time DESC`